# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{2x(\sin x)^2+\frac{2x^7+x^8}{3x^2+x^4}-\arctan(2x^3)}{\ln(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2})-2x^2+xe^{-{1\over x}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

To start with, the term $xe^{-{1\over x}}$ can be ignored.Then splitting the term $\ln(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2})=\ln(1+x^2)-\ln(1-x^2)$ and expanding both of them up to order 3 we have in the denominator $2x^2+{2x^6\over 3}-2x^2={2x^6\over3}$
As for the numerator $\arctan(2x^3)\sim2x^3$ and ${2x^7+x^8\over 3x^2+x^4}\sim{2\over3}x^5$.So if we expand $\sin x$ up to order 2,then take the square (ignoring higher order terms) and multiply by $2x$ we have $2x(\sin x)^2\sim2x^3-{2\over3}x^5$ which cancels out with the other terms,giving us an indeterminate form.So I think we should have $x^6$ term in the numerator.
But if I expand $\sin x$ up to order 3 and take square, I fail to obtain $x^5$ term(so that when multiplied by $2x$ gives me $x^6$).How can this be done?

Comment: Where did you find this problem

Comment: While I know you want to determine the steps to find the limit, that limit (according to *Mathematica* and a simple plot) is $1/2$.

Comment: @Zach This is question from a previous exam of my course

Comment: You really do need to evaluate each piece up to $x^6.$ There is cancellation among the lower degree terms, including some coefficients that come out $0$ in the first place.

Comment: It looks like $0$:  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nrq5rm6ooj

Comment: @JimB, correct. I think I found what was missing in the development. See answer below.

Comment: @clathratus  I think your graphics package is showing some round-off error issues.  Try substituting the simplified $\frac{x^5 (x+2)}{x^2+3}$ for $\frac{x^8+2 x^7}{x^4+3 x^2}$ (as we can do because we only consider $x>0$).  You'll then get the curve I see in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items below are called Taylor Series. This is a good way to reduce errors, in cases where L'Hospital's method leads to messy derivatives. One may take time and get each series correct. In this case, all the series derive from that for $$ \frac{1}{1+t} = 1 - t + t^2 - t^3 + t^4 - t^5 \cdots, $$ which leads fairly quickly to series for $1/(3+t),$ for $\log(1+t),$ and for $\arctan t$

$$ $$

To confirm the first step below, multiply the right hand side by $x^2 + 3$ and notice the cancellations:

$$  \frac{1}{x^2 + 3} = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{x^4}{27} - \frac{x^6}{81}  + \cdots $$
$$  \frac{1}{x^4 + 3x^2} = \frac{1}{3x^2} - \frac{1}{9} + \frac{x^2}{27} - \frac{x^4}{81}  + \cdots $$
$$  \frac{x^8 + 2x^7}{x^4 + 3x^2} = \frac{2x^5}{3} + \frac{x^6}{3} - \frac{2x^7}{9} - \frac{x^8}{9}  + \cdots $$

$$  2x \sin^2 x = 2 x^3 - \frac{2x^5}{3} + \frac{4x^7}{45} -  \cdots $$
$$  \arctan (2x^3)  = 2 x^3 - \frac{8x^9}{3}  -  \cdots $$

The numerator is $$  \frac{x^6}{3} - \frac{2x^7}{15}   + \cdots  $$
The denominator is $$  \frac{2x^6}{3} + \frac{2x^{10}}{5}   + \cdots  $$

giving limit $1/2$

Comment: How can we directly obtain Taylor series of $\frac{1}{x^2+3}$ from $\frac{1}{1+t}$?

Comment: @TuranNəsibli substitute $t = \frac{x^2}{3}.$ That gives the series for $\frac{3}{3+x^2},$ so you need to divide the whole thing by $3$ when you are otherwise done.

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake by considering only the first asymptotic term of the algebraic fraction. Be careful:
$$\frac{2x^5+x^6}{3+x^2}=\frac{2}{3}x^5 + \frac{1}{3}x^6 + o(x^6).$$
Then your limit gives $\frac{1}{2}$, as results from the comment by [JimB](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/186064/jimb).

Comment: I didn't really get the way you obtained it,could you give me more details?

Comment: @TuranNəsibli $$\frac{2x^5+x^6}{3+x^2} = \frac{2}{3}x^5 +\left(-\frac{2}{3}x^5 + \frac{2x^5+x^6}{3+x^2}\right)$$ and then look what is left in parenthesis.

Comment: I don't recall seeing anything like this throughout course.While simplifying the fraction I just neglected higher order terms both in numerator and denominator and obtained ${2\over3}x^5$

Comment: @TuranNəsibli this only gives you dominant term, which cancels out with other terms in the overall numerator. In that case you must consider also what you had neglected before, as when you further develop the MacLaurin polynomial of sine or logarithm. By the way of course you'd obtain the same results taking derivatives, or as shown in another answer. I usually proceed as I showed you here.

Comment: I understand this,but I thought that term would come from MacLaurin expansion of sine,and I don't know how to obtain term ${x^6\over 3} $ from fraction

Comment: @TuranNəsibli I put that in my answer.

Comment: @WillJagy technique you applied isn't familiar to me.What is it called?

Comment: Exacly, you can use @WillJagy approach, which is very fine, of course. Or, as I showed you right above, here, by subracting dominant term to the original fraction.

Comment: @Matteo is what you are doing here called asymptotic expansion?

Comment: @TuranNəsibli what I am doing allows you to obtain it. Alternatively use $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i  + o\left(x^{n}\right)$$.

Comment: @TuranNəsibli the series used in our answers would be found by looking up Taylor series; in English, the phrase asymptotic expansion is more general, especially referring to approximations that do not converge... Anyway, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series  contrast with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion#Examples

Comment: @WillJagy I had never seen Taylor polynomials used on fractions like this.If I use the definition of Taylor series directly on my fraction this results with disaster.So I am currently analyzing your steps.Thanks, by the way

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series approach suggested by @Matteo and @WillJagy is the way to go.  Here is that approach made a bit more explicit:

1. Divide the numerator and denominator by x^6.
2. Construct the resulting first order Taylor series for both numerator and denominator.
3. Observe what the limits must be.

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \, \frac{-\tan ^{-1}\left(2 x^3\right)+\frac{(x+2) x^5}{x^2+3}+2 x \sin ^2(x)}{x \exp \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)-2 x^2+\log \left(\frac{x^2+1}{1-x^2}\right)}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \,{ {(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2 x}{15}+o(x^2) )}\over{(\frac{2}{3}+e^{-1/x}(\frac{1}{x^5}+o(x^2)))}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Here is a plot of the function:

[image: Plot of function near zero]